# type casting issue in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, casting, nullable

ive have type casting issue and i need help as soon as possible :D,   now the issue is ive methods to check nullable values for datetime and int types... but im getting type cast error...

method :

```
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(string stringValue)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, out dateValue)) { return dateValue; } 
     else {     return DateTime.MinValue; }
    }
```

using the method its in my object class :

```
 Objects<DateTime?>.ToNullableDateTime(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblCommitmentDate")).Text);
```

Error :

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Why don't you return `DateTime` in your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a return type of `DateTime?` and trying to return a `DateTime`.